# Split a sentence to word columns using loops or functions in R?

Tags: r, nlp

I have a dataframe corpus in R which looks like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2GH6.png)
And I want to create n-grams(upto 5-grams) using loops or functions. currently, I am doing it manually in this way:

Sample corpus structure:

{"colleagues were also at the other two events in aberystwyth and flint and by all accounts had a great time", 
"the lineup was whittled down to a more palatable five in  when the bing crosby souffle going my way bested both gaslight and double indemnity proving oscar voters have always had a taste for pabulum", 
"felt my first earthquake today whole building at work was shaking", 
"she is the kind of mother friend and woman i aspire everyday to be", 
"she was processed and released pending a court appearance", 
"watching some sunday night despite the sadness i have been feeling i also feel very blessed and happy to be carrying another miracle", 
"every night when we listen to poohs heartbeat our hearts feel so much happiness and peace",}

```
`onegram <- NGramTokenizer(corpusdf, Weka_control(min=1, max=1))
   onegram <- data.frame(table(onegram))
  onegram <- onegram[order(onegram$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
colnames(onegram) <- c("Word", "Freq")
onegram [1:15,]


bigram <- NGramTokenizer(corpusdf, Weka_control(min=2, max=2, delimiters = tokendelim))
bigram <- data.frame(table(bigram))
bigram <- bigram[order(bigram$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
colnames(bigram) <- c("Word", "Freq")
bigram [1:15,]`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the data from the image using `dput(corpusdf)`. This will make it a lot easier to give you an answer.

Comment: you can use `NGramTokenizer(corpusdf, Weka_control(min=1, max=5))` to create ngrams from 1 to 5 words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the function NGramTokenizer and couldn't get it to work. So here is a solution in `quanteda`, which produces individual tokens objects for each iteration (gram_1 for onegram, gram_2 for bigrams and so on):

```
corpusdf <- data.frame(text = c("colleagues were also at the other two events in aberystwyth and flint and by all accounts had a great time", "the lineup was whittled down to a more palatable five in when the bing crosby souffle going my way bested both gaslight and double indemnity proving oscar voters have always had a taste for pabulum", "felt my first earthquake today whole building at work was shaking", "she is the kind of mother friend and woman i aspire everyday to be", "she was processed and released pending a court appearance", "watching some sunday night despite the sadness i have been feeling i also feel very blessed and happy to be carrying another miracle", "every night when we listen to poohs heartbeat our hearts feel so much happiness and peace"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library("quanteda")
tokens <- tokens(corpusdf$text, what = "word")
for (n in seq_len(5)) {
  temp <- tokens_ngrams(tokens, n = n, skip = 0L, concatenator = "_")
  temp <- data.frame(table(unlist(temp)),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(temp) <- c("Word", "Freq")
  temp <- temp[order(temp$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
  assign(paste0("gram_", n), temp)
}

head(gram_2)
```

Output looks like this:

```
> head(gram_2)
       Word Freq
53    had_a    2
101   to_be    2
1   a_court    1
2   a_great    1
3    a_more    1
4   a_taste    1
```

Update: After I realised `NGramTokenizer` belongs to the `RWeka` package and not `tm`, @phiver 's answer works for me

```
ngrams <- RWeka::NGramTokenizer(corpusdf, Weka_control(min=1, max=5))
ngrams <- data.frame(table(ngrams),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ngrams <- ngrams[order(ngrams$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
head(ngrams)
```

However, this mixes up all ngrams which does not make much sense if you want to rank frequencies (onegrams will naturally be on top). So here is a loop solution:

```
for (n in seq_len(5)) {
  temp <- RWeka::NGramTokenizer(corpusdf, Weka_control(min=n, max=n))
  temp <- data.frame(table(unlist(temp)),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(temp) <- c("Word", "Freq")
  temp <- temp[order(temp$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
  assign(paste0("gram_", n), temp)
}

head(gram_2)
```